# NGINX One Domain - Several webservers on internal IP

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, nginx, debian, ip

I have a case I am not sure how to manage and would like some advice.

### Current:

One domain-name - one external ip. One already working Debian Server
with NGINX for hosting webpages.

```
So, as it is now, I have *.domain.com pointing to server.internal.ip.
Internal IP is on a 192.168.1.x/24 network and all works just as intended.
```

### New Case:

I am asked to create CNAME's to the domain.com, ie

```
cname1.domain.com
cname2.domain.com
cname3.domain.com
```

and so forth.

What I need to do now is point the corresponding cname to a corresponding server, ie

```
cname1.domain.com to server1.internal.ip
cname2.domain.com to server2.internal.ip
..
cname9.domain.com to server9.internal.ip
```

> I still need to make sure all other requests not belonging to a CNAME
>   (ie *.domain.com) belongs to the original server.internal.ip.

I am not getting more external ip numbers, I have do use what I have.

How would I go about doing that with NGINX?

I am assuming I somehow need to set up the already working server.internal.ip to redirect requests on port 80 based on cname to the corresponding new internal servers?

My router that is in use today is equipped with DD-WRT.

Any tips/ pointers towards a HOWTO that I did not manage to find would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have port `80` forwarded on the router to the server `server.internal.ip`, so this server gets all traffic  going to public IP on port 80.

The you can have several name-based virtual hosts on `server.internal.ip` working as a forward proxy for other servers.

On `server.internal.ip`, you can add something like following to your `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name cname1.domain.com;

    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass        http://server1.internal.ip:80/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header   Host cname1.domain.com;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
server {
    listen 192.168.1.1:80;
    server_name cname2.domain.com;

    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;
    location ~ ^/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass        http://server2.internal.ip:80/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header   Host cname2.domain.com;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Header `X-Real-IP` can be used for logging the IP request came from (otherwise can be omitted).
These virtual hosts will have precedence over your `*.domain.com` ([Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html))